# controller to delete row in table based on model variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a HttpPost controller which adds a School model booking into the Schools Db (which saves info like School Name, School Date, School Id). Now I need to delete the row in Dates Db which Date is the same Date as the one just entered into School Db e.g. if School model date entered was 13/07/2019, I want to find the row in Dates Db which has the date - 13/07/2019 and then delete this row from the table

My controller so far:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Booking(School model)
    {
        db.Schools.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();


        //make chosen school date unavailable in datepicker
        Datepicker date = db.Dates.Find(model.Date); 
        db.Dates.Remove(date);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Booking");
    }
```

School model (Schools Db context):

```
namespace BookingSys.Models
{
  public class School
  {
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
  }
}
```

DatePicker model (Dates Db context):

```
namespace BookingSys.Models
{
  public class Datepicker
  {
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LecturerId { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
  }
}
```

I am currently getting the following error when I click submit in the View to create a School model:

System.ArgumentException: 'The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity. See inner exception for details.
Parameter name: keyValues'
EntitySqlException: The argument types 'Edm.Int32' and 'Edm.DateTime' are incompatible for this operation. Near WHERE predicate, line 1, column 62.

[image: a busy cat]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok. so what is the error you are having deleting the date from the Date table?. I don't really know the structure of your db but is deleting what you really want? why not have a column say `deleted` and mark an item as deleted?, there is no `Ctrl+Z` after deleting.

Comment: @bosco I do not want to delete the date field in Dates Db Context, I want to delete the row which has the same date as the date in Schools Db Context. e.g. if School model date entered was 13/07/2019, I want to find the row in Dates Db which has the date - 13/07/2019 and then delete this row from the table

Comment: Ok. since you want to still delete the row, what is the error you are having with your present code??

Comment: @Bosco I have updated my original question mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the lamda expression and also use `First` or `FirstOrDefault`

change this line

```
Datepicker date = db.Dates.Find(model.Date);
```

To

```
Datepicker date = db.Dates.First(m => m.Date == model.Date);
```

OR

```
//if you are not sure if the date exists in both tables
Datepicker date = db.Dates.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Date == model.Date); 
// then check for null before deleting
```

`Find()` requires the value of the primary key of the table and you need to get the data bay Date